# useing web3 in React has error : webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default

Tags: reactjs, webpack, web3js

I tried use web3 in Reactjs but when I import web3 it has error :

> webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
> This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

I use nodejs 14.18 and webpack 5.5.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this error with changing react-scripts version to '^4.0.3' according to this link : https://forum.moralis.io/t/problem-with-web3ui/12725/5

Answer (score 0):

Use resolutions in package.json **(only work on yarn)**

```
  "resolutions": {
    "webpack": "5.5.0" // <- Add require version
  }
```

```
yarn install
```

Example from my Code

[image: Example of my Code]